# What is OpenWhisk and how to setup a cluster using this technology?

Tags: serverless, ibm-cloud, openwhisk

On IBM bluemix platform it is possible to write cloud functions using OpenWhisk, but what is OpenWhisk and how to setup a cluster using this technology?

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OPENWHISK/OpenWhisk+Project+Wiki

Answer (score 1):

According to [this GitHub readme](https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk)

> OpenWhisk is a serverless event-based programming service.

In order to get an idea how to setup this tool on a cluster one could run the following code that is defined in the readme:

> ```
> # Clone openwhisk
> git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk.git openwhisk
>
> # Change directory to tools/vagrant
> cd openwhisk/tools/vagrant
>
> # Run script to create vm and run hello action
> ./hello
> ```